# How to open a Win32 dialogbox from inside a VST plug-in?

Tags: winapi, dialog, vst

How to open a Win32 dialogbox from inside a VST plug-in? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the standard MessageBox() call, [as described in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884850/display-alert-with-custom-button-titles-on-windows).  Not sure if this will work in a plugin without a GUI editor, though.

Comment: Indeed. In fact I would like to have a text edit field... that's not immediate. I personnaly resolved it with Qt and a QInputDialog::getText.